# How to group the matrices which are in a relationship

Tags: python, numpy

I like have several matrices. I first check if they are in shifting relationship. If yes, I want to group them. if not I like to separate them. For example, d) and g) are shifting products of a); e) and h) are shifting products of b); f) is shifting product of c). Then I like to group (a, d, g); (b, e, h); (c, f).

```
def is_shift(set1, set2): 
    shift = None  # will store a tuple of delta_x, delta_y
    for (x1, y1), (x2, y2) in zip(set1, set2): 
        cur_shift = x1 - x1, y1 - y2 
        if not shift:  # the first pair of points
            shift = cur_shift 
        elif shift != cur_shift: # shifted the same way as the first one?
            return False 
    return True 

matrices1 = np.array([
    [(1, 1), (2, 1)],
    [(1, 2), (2, 1)],
    [(1, 3), (2, 1)],
    [(1, 2), (2, 2)],
    [(1, 3), (2, 2)],
    [(2, 3), (3, 1)],
    [(2, 3), (3, 3)],
    [(2, 2), (3, 2)]
])
matrices2 = array([
    [(1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1)],
    [(1, 2), (2, 1), (3, 1)],
    [(1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 2)], 
    [(1, 2), (2, 2), (3, 2)], 
    [(1, 3), (2, 2), (3, 2)], 
    [(2, 3), (3, 1), (3, 2)],
    [(1, 3), (2, 3), (3, 3)], 
    [(2, 2), (3, 1), (4, 4)],
    [(1, 1), (3, 3), (4, 1)]
    ])
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: what is starting index? (0,0) or (1,1)

Comment: They are matrices

Comment: How the indices and points in the plot are related? @Binh Thien

Comment: `(1, 1), (2, 1)` can be shifted to `(2, 3), (3, 3)`, so far so good but...  Is `(3, 3), (2, 3)`  also a shift of `(1, 1), (2, 1)`  ?

Comment: yes @gboffi, by a vector (1, 2).

Comment: Let me ask you again, if we can say that a _matrix_ of yours contains 2 points in a 2D plane, my question can be reformulated like this:  _"The points in a_ matrix _are **ordered**?"_  — again, is `(1, 1), (2, 1)` the same _matrix_ as `(2, 1), (1, 1)` ?

Comment: yes, ordering is neglected. we should consider (1, 1), (2, 1) and (2, 1), (1, 1) are same.

Comment: The points in _matrix_ `h` have coordinates `2,  2` and `3, 1` — not `2, 2` and `3, 1` .  Please correct the code AND the picture.

Comment: How do you call the function?

Comment: @Mad Physicist, what function do you mean?

Comment: The only one in your code?

Comment: I think the function can be called in for loop like: for item in matrices: for i in range(0, len(matrices): for j in range(0, len(matrices): is_shift(item[i], item[j])

Answer (score 1):

Edit:

1. I have corrected the numbers in the last 2D *matrix* to match the position of the two points in the *matrix* `h` in the OP's original figure.
2. I have simplified the `for` loop
3. I have enhanced the printout of the resulting groups (that are `a, d, h`, `b, e, g` and `c, f` as stated by the OP).

---

A possible solution, in face of an ambiguous description of the problem, is to group your *matrices* in a dictionary indexed by the increments in the coordinates between the two points in a *matrix*.

```
In [20]: from numpy import array 
    ...:  
    ...: matrices = array([ 
    ...:     [(1, 2), (2, 1)], 
    ...:     [(1, 3), (2, 1)], 
    ...:     [(1, 2), (2, 2)], 
    ...:     [(1, 3), (2, 2)], 
    ...:     [(2, 3), (3, 1)], 
    ...:     [(2, 3), (3, 3)], 
    ...:     [(2, 2), (3, 1)] 
    ...: ]) 
    ...: 
    ...: shifted_groups = {} 
    ...:  
    ...: for m in matrices:
    ...:     dx, dy = m[1]-m[0] 
    ...:     shifted_groups.setdefault((dx, dy), []).append(m) 
    ...:  
    ...: for k, v in shifted_groups.items(): 
    ...:     print("%10r: "%(k,), ''.join("%r"%[list(list(r) for r in m) for m in v]))    
    (1, 0):  [[[1, 1], [2, 1]], [[1, 2], [2, 2]], [[2, 3], [3, 3]]]
   (1, -1):  [[[1, 2], [2, 1]], [[1, 3], [2, 2]], [[2, 2], [3, 1]]]
   (1, -2):  [[[1, 3], [2, 1]], [[2, 3], [3, 1]]]


In [21]:
```

Comment: I am sorry for unclear question. The shifting here can be understood like following. The vector (0, 1) shifts the set (a) of two points having coordinates (1, 1) and (2, 1) ---> set (d) having (1, 2) and (2, 2) respectively. Similarly, by a vector (1, 2), the set (a) of two points (1, 1) and (2, 1) becomes the set (g) of (2, 3) and (3, 3). Similarly, by a vector (1, 1), the set (d) of two points (1, 2) and (2, 2) transform to the set (g) of two points (2, 3) and (3,3). That's why the set (a), (d) and (g) are same. It is not because the distance between 2 points in each set.

Comment: Ahem, if you add the same vector to 2 points ① the 2D distance between the points remains the same (and this is my `dx, dy` computation) and ② the order of the points matter.  Please do not think just in terms of an original formulation, sometimes a problem gets waaay easier if you look at it from a different view point.

Comment: I am afraid that is not. if there are 3 points or more in each set, how can it work? Please help me consider an example in the edited question?